# How can I get a value from attribute webconfig c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configurationmanager

I need to get a single value from attribute element, my webconfig is like this:

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="Seccion" type="ManejoConfiguracion.SeccionConfig,ManejoConfiguracion"/>
  </configSections>
  <Seccion>
    <BD>
      <add key="name" value="dbKey"/>
      <add key="user" value="userBD"/>
      <add key="pass" value="123BD"/>
    </BD>
    <ReportingService>
    <add key="name" value="Reporting" />
    <add key="user" value="userReport" />
    </ReportingService>
  </Seccion>
```

How can I get "**userReport**" as value,this value belongs to the subsection "ReportingService", I need the value just for assign to a label. I get a section like this:

```
public class SeccionConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {

       [ConfigurationProperty("ReportingService")]

        public ElementoColeccionConfig Seccion 
        {
            get { return ((ElementoColeccionConfig)(base["ReportingService"])); }

        }
    }
```

My ConfigurationCollection class like this:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ElementoConfig ))]
    public class ElementoColeccionConfig : ConfigurationElementCollection {
  protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new ElementoConfig ();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((ElementoConfig)(element)).key ;
        }

        public ElementoConfig this[int idx]
        {
            get
            {
                return (ElementoConfig)BaseGet(idx);
            }
        }
     }
```

And my ConfigurationElement like this:

```
public class ElementoConfig : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("key", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string key
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base["key"]));
            }
            set
            {
                base["key"] = value;
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("value", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)]
        public string value
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base["value"]));
            }
            set
            {
                base["value"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SeccionConfig sc = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Seccion") as SeccionConfig;
```